# How to mock scanner and file class

Tags: java, mockito

This is the method which I want to test

```
  public void sendMailWitchChanges(JobEntity job, DirectoryEntity directory, FileIdFilePathFileContentEntity fileByPath, LocalDateTime date, String fileName) throws IOException, MessagingException {
    String fileAfterChange = new Scanner(new File(directory.getDirectory() + fileByPath.getFileName())).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();


    fileIdFilePathFileContentEntityRepository.setNewFileContent(fileByPath.getFileId(), fileAfterChange);
    String newContent = StringUtils.difference(fileByPath.getFileContent(), fileAfterChange);
//irrelevant code
}
```

My test:

```
@Test
void sendMailWitchChanges() throws MessagingException, IOException {
    File fileMock = Mockito.mock(File.class);
    Scanner scannerMock = Mockito.mock(Scanner.class);
    when(new Scanner(any(File.class))).thenReturn(scannerMock);
    when(scannerMock.useDelimiter(anyString()).next()).thenReturn("afterChanges");
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
    JobEntity job = new JobEntity("uuid", now, 1, Set.of(user));
    DirectoryEntity directory = new DirectoryEntity(1, "directory");
    FileIdFilePathFileContentEntity fileIdFilePathFileContentEntity = new FileIdFilePathFileContentEntity(1, "fileName", "fileContent");
    mailService.sendMailWitchChanges(job, directory, fileIdFilePathFileContentEntity, now, "fileName"):Mockito.verify(mailService, verificationData -> times(1)).sendMailWitchChanges(job, directory, fileIdFilePathFileContentEntity, now, "fileName");
}
```

But I'm getting `NullPointerException` at `when(new Scanner(any(File.class))).thenReturn(scannerMock);`

How this test should look like?

Comment: [Mockito cannot mock constructor calls](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ#what-are-the-limitations-of-mockito). --- I would advise to use a file/directory with known content for the test.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods and Constructors are difficult at best, impossible at worst to mock. However, with some smart code structure and a healthy/documented set of assumptions, one can unit test their code and be assured it does what you need it to do.

I think your main problem here is your function signature does not lend itself to testing. You should try to think: I need to test my code, not the JDK's code.

```
public void sendMailWitchChanges(JobEntity job, DirectoryEntity directory, FileIdFilePathFileContentEntity fileByPath, LocalDateTime date, String fileName) throws IOException, MessagingException {
```

If I were conducting a code review, I would see that File and Directory probably are an overlap and indicate an underlying structural issue. I would find a way to eliminate those two variables. If I were successful doing that, I could eliminate testing of JDK code (Scanner, File, etc), and focus more on testing my code.

In this particular case, passing an `InputStream` with the contents probably eliminates the need for all of these mocks. During Unit Testing, one can use `ByteArrayInputStream` to test your code and gives flexibility for more complex scenarios during an Integration Test.